# How to display multiple columns in TDBLookupComboBox?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, lookup

I tried setting ListField property to "Column1;Column2" but only Column1 is diplayed. Is it even possible to diplay multiple columns in this component or I must search for some 3rd party solution?

Using C++ Builder XE6...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple columns in `ListField` will only show those columns during dropdown. If you want to show multiple fields even in closeup mode you should add a calculated field for use in `ListField`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still, only the first column appears.

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you add a calculated field to the field in the list source which concatenates both columns and did you select this field as ListField in the combobox?

Comment: That is not what I want. I don't want to have connected strings in one column but each in his own column.

Comment: Then you are probably out of luck here. A combobox has no means to display "columns" inside its edit field part.